# Sending an image captured using ov7670 using arduino and serially transmit it to python

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, communication, python

I am working on using an ov7670 camera module with arduino uno,capturing the image frame wise and transmitting the image serially line by line of each frame to python for image processing, however i am getting very distorted images once is use the serial.write() command,how do i send the bytes without using serial.write().

[This is the link i used for setting up the Ov7670](https://circuitjournal.com/arduino-OV7670-to-pc)

Comment: You didn't show your code, nor a sample of a distorted image, nor your python code. What exactly makes you think, that `Serial.write()` is the problem here?